# RailsAdmin not working with Pundit - Pundit::AuthorizationNotPerformedError at / RailsAdmin::MainController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin, pundit

I'm using Devise and Pundit gems in a Ruby on Rails application.
I'm trying to implement RailsAdmin in order to set up a simple admin interface for my non-tech team members, on the URL 'myapp.com/admin', but going to this URL raises the following error :

> Pundit::AuthorizationNotPerformedError at /
>   RailsAdmin::MainController

This error is raised by the file lib/pundit.rb in the following method:

```html
def verify_authorized
    raise AuthorizationNotPerformedError, self.class unless pundit_policy_authorized?
  end
```

I understand this is linked to Pundit's policies but cannot find my way through the changes to perform.

Here is what I've tried until now :

In my Gemfile, I have installed :

> gem "rails_admin"

and

> gem "rails_admin_pundit", :github => "sudosu/rails_admin_pundit"

Then, in my terminal, I ran

> 'bundle'

In my initializers, I have :

```html
RailsAdmin.config do |config|
  ## == Devise ==
  config.authenticate_with do
    warden.authenticate! scope: :user
  end
  config.current_user_method(&:current_user)

  ## == Pundit ==
  config.authorize_with :pundit
end
```

In my controllers/application_controller.rb, I have the following code :

```html
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  include Pundit

  after_action :verify_authorized, except: :index, unless: :devise_controller?
  after_action :verify_policy_scoped, only: :index, unless: :devise_controller?

  rescue_from Pundit::NotAuthorizedError, with: :user_not_authorized

  def user_not_authorized
    flash[:alert] = "You are not authorized to perform this action."
    redirect_to(root_path)
  end

  def default_url_options
    { host: ENV['HOST'] || 'localhost:3000' }
  end

    private

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << [:first_name, :last_name, :bio, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :photo, :photo_cache]
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) << [:first_name, :last_name, :bio, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :photo, :photo_cache]
  end

end
```

Last, in my policies/application_policy.rb (see at the end the 'def rails_admin?' method), I have :

```html
class ApplicationPolicy
  attr_reader :user, :record

  def initialize(user, record)
    @user = user
    @record = record
  end

  def index?
    false
  end

  def show?
    scope.where(:id => record.id).exists?
  end

  def create?
    false
  end

  def new?
    create?
  end

  def update?
    false
  end

  def edit?
    update?
  end

  def destroy?
    false
  end

  def scope
    Pundit.policy_scope!(user, record.class)
  end

  class Scope
    attr_reader :user, :scope

    def initialize(user, scope)
      @user = user
      @scope = scope
    end

    def resolve
      scope
    end
  end

  def rails_admin?(action)
    case action
      when :dashboard
        user.admin?
      when :index
        user.admin?
      when :show
        user.admin?
      when :new
        user.admin?
      when :edit
        user.admin?
      when :destroy
        user.admin?
      when :export
        user.admin?
      when :history
        user.admin?
      when :show_in_app
        user.admin?
      else
        raise ::Pundit::NotDefinedError, "unable to find policy #{action} for #{record}."
    end
  end
end
```

Would you have any idea about what I am missing?
Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved my problem. 
Seems like there is a little bug in rails_admin_pundit gem. 
The following change, found in a commit made on the rails_admin_pundit gem's GitHub repository but ignored until now made the job!

In my Gemfile, instead of calling :

> gem "rails_admin_pundit", :github => "sudosu/rails_admin_pundit"

I called :

> gem "rails_admin_pundit", :github => "Samy-Amar/rails_admin_pundit"

Basically, the commit added one extra line in

> lib/rails_admin/extensions/pundit/authorization_adapter.rb

You can see the details of this tiny change on this page: https://github.com/Samy-Amar/rails_admin_pundit/commit/4017395e5e715e2f1fd95918bc4bb9b76d272b25

Hope this will help!